# Procedimiento almacenado borrar_registro

Tags: c#, oracle, .net, wpf

tengo un problema al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado desde c# (el procedimiento esta en sqlDeveloper). Intento ejecutar este pero me da este error, se que problema de la foreign key, pero no sé como arreglarlo, si puedieran ayudarme un poco lo agradeceria adjunto codigo y procedimiento correspondiente.

este es el error

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (PROYECTO.FK_COMPANIA) violated -
>   child record found ORA-06512: at "PROYECTO.SP_BORRAR_REGISTRO", line 5
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

este es mi boton borrar

```
 private async void btnEliminar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();

        OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("SP_BORRAR_REGISTRO", conexion);
        comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRut.Text))
        {
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error!", "Todos los Campos Deben ser Llenados.");
        }
        else
        {
            comando.Parameters.Add("RUT", OracleType.VarChar).Value = txtRut.Text;

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Exito!", "Registro Eliminado Correctamente.");
        }
        conexion.Close();
        this.updateDataGrid();
    }
```

este es mi procedimiento

```
    create or replace procedure SP_BORRAR_REGISTRO_US (RUT IN VARCHAR2)
as 
 vrut VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) := RUT;
begin
    delete from dato_usuario where rut = vrut;
end;
```

y los datos de las tablas

**tabla compania**

```
RUT VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
DIRECCION   VARCHAR2(45 BYTE)
RAZON_SOCIAL    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
NUMERO_TELEFONICO   VARCHAR2(45 BYTE)
ACTIVO  NUMBER(38,0)
```

**tabla datos_usuario**

```
RUT VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
APELLIDO    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
NUMERO_TELEFONICO   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
FECHA_CREACION  DATE
FECHA_NACIMIENTO    DATE
FK_COMPANIA VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
FK_ROL  NUMBER(38,0)
FECHA_CREACION  DATE
```

Comment: CUál es la definición de esa FK? La solución es que no borres un registro de `datos_usuario` si hay registros en `compania` que dependen de él, así funciona la FK. La solución es que revises la lógica de tu procedimiento para decidir qué quieres borrar.

Comment: PD. SQLdeveloper es el editor, pero la BD posiblemente sea Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esto indica es que estás intentando borrar un registro de una tabla padre (a la que se hace referencia mediante una clave externa), pero existe un registro en la tabla secundaria.

Verifica, tomando como referencia las FK, en qué otra tabla estás usando el **RUT** que aparece en **datos_usuario**, en este caso yo intuyo que **compania** tiene un registro con el **RUT** de **datos_usuario**, por tanto al borrar en **datos_usuario** estás dejando "huérfano" el registro de **compania**.. y veo que tienes una FK llamada **FK_ROL**, comprueba eso también.

Lo que debes hacer en este caso, según yo, es borrar primero el registro con el RUT de las tablas hijas (compania y rol) y LUEGO cuando ya no queden, borras el registro de **datos_usuario** que sería como un DELETE en CASCADA pero "manual".

**RESPUESTA CORTA: Borra el RUT de compania y rol y luego de datos_usuario.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_BORRAR_REGISTRO_US (RUT IN VARCHAR2)
as 
 vrut VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) := RUT;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM compania WHERE rut = vrut;
    DELETE FROM rol WHERE rut = vrut;
    DELETE FROM dato_usuario WHERE rut = vrut;
END;
```

Un saludo.

Ah! una recomendación, cuando uses Procedimientos Almacenados, trata de que los parámetros tengan un prefijo, por ejemplo "**P_**RUT", o "**v**RUT", así los puedes llamar directamente sin tener que volver a referenciarlos antes del **BEGIN** y que no coincidan con nombres de columnas.